# Android parcelable class not fount exception in CI

Tags: android, jenkins, android-testing

I write a project in Android studio 2.3.3, I have JUnit test, also I use Jenkins as CI. My tasks in CI are clean,testDevDebugUnitTest. In past, my tests were working fine. Yesterday I removed folder build from my Android project and after that testDevDebugUnitTest always failed in CI.but In Android studio all is ok.

Stacktrace I am getting is as below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Parcelable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at ru.alfabank.oavdo.amc.base.models.Amount$Parser.parse(Amount.kt:135)
    at ru.alfabank.oavdo.amc.base.models.Amount$Parser.parse(Amount.kt:114)
    at ru.alfabank.oavdo.amc.base.models.AmountTest.parseTest(AmountTest.kt:78)

    Caused by:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Parcelable
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 15 more
```

I googled about this and found almost nothing, except that remove gradle folder, but after that project doesn't compile. Maybe anyone met this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make your model class implements with Serializable.